# Keyboard pushing admob advertisment up

Tags: java, android, admob

I have an android application. I just added the sample advertisments to my app, and I keep having problems with the ad over my EditText.

When I click on the EditText, the advertisment which is at the bottom of the screen moves up above the keyboard.

My code is below:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    tools:context="org.alexwebber.frc.strongholdcalculator.MainActivity">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/autonomous"
        android:textSize="25sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:id="@+id/autoLabel" />

    <GridLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="150dp"
        android:id="@+id/autogrid"
        android:layout_below="@+id/autoLabel"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="1dp">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:text="@string/defreached"
            android:id="@+id/defenseReached"
            android:textSize="17sp"
            android:layout_row="0"
            android:layout_column="0"
            android:layout_columnSpan="13" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:text="@string/defcrossed"
            android:textSize="17sp"
            android:id="@+id/defcrossed"
            android:layout_row="1"
            android:layout_column="0" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:text="@string/lowgoal"
            android:textSize="17sp"
            android:id="@+id/lowgoalauto"
            android:layout_row="2"
            android:layout_column="0" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:text="@string/highgoal"
            android:textSize="17sp"
            android:id="@+id/highgoalauto"
            android:layout_row="3"
            android:layout_column="0" />

        <EditText
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:inputType="number"
            android:ems="10"
            android:id="@+id/autodefreach"
            android:textSize="12sp"
            android:layout_row="0"
            android:layout_column="24"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:text="@string/total" />

        <EditText
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:inputType="number"
            android:ems="10"
            android:id="@+id/autodefcross"
            android:textSize="12sp"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:text="@string/total"
            android:layout_row="1"
            android:layout_column="24" />

        <EditText
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:inputType="number"
            android:ems="10"
            android:id="@+id/autolowgoal"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:text="@string/total"
            android:textSize="12sp"
            android:layout_row="2"
            android:layout_column="24" />

        <EditText
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:inputType="number"
            android:ems="10"
            android:id="@+id/autohighgoal"
            android:textSize="12sp"
            android:text="@string/total"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:layout_row="3"
            android:layout_column="24" />
    </GridLayout>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/teleop"
        android:id="@+id/teleopLabel"
        android:layout_below="@+id/autogrid"
        android:textSize="25sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="0dp" />

    <GridLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="175dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/teleopLabel"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="1dp"
        android:id="@+id/gridLayout">


        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/defcrossed"
            android:id="@+id/defcrossedtele"
            android:textSize="17sp"
            android:layout_row="0"
            android:layout_column="0" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/lowgoal"
            android:id="@+id/lowgoaltele"
            android:textSize="17sp"
            android:layout_row="1"
            android:layout_column="0" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/highgoal"
            android:id="@+id/highgoaltele"
            android:textSize="17sp"
            android:layout_row="2"
            android:layout_column="0" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/challegedTower"
            android:id="@+id/challengestower"
            android:textSize="17sp"
            android:layout_row="3"
            android:layout_column="0" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/scaledTower"
            android:id="@+id/scaledtowertele"
            android:textSize="17sp"
            android:layout_row="4"
            android:layout_column="0" />

        <EditText
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:inputType="number"
            android:ems="10"
            android:id="@+id/teledefcross"
            android:text="@string/total"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:layout_row="0"
            android:textSize="12sp"
            android:layout_column="13" />

        <EditText
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:inputType="number"
            android:ems="10"
            android:id="@+id/telelowgoal"
            android:text="@string/total"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:layout_row="1"
            android:textSize="12sp"
            android:layout_column="13" />

        <EditText
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:inputType="number"
            android:ems="10"
            android:id="@+id/telehighgoal"
            android:text="@string/total"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:layout_row="2"
            android:textSize="12sp"
            android:layout_column="13" />

        <EditText
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:inputType="number"
            android:ems="10"
            android:id="@+id/telechallengedtower"
            android:text="@string/total"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:layout_row="3"
            android:textSize="12sp"
            android:layout_column="13" />

        <EditText
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:inputType="number"
            android:ems="10"
            android:id="@+id/telescaledtower"
            android:text="@string/total"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:layout_row="4"
            android:textSize="12sp"
            android:layout_column="13" />

    </GridLayout>

    <GridLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_below="@+id/gridLayout"
        android:id="@+id/rpgrid">
        <CheckBox
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/breach"
            android:id="@+id/breach"
            android:layout_marginTop="1dp"
            android:checked="false"
            android:layout_row="0"
            android:layout_column="0"
            android:layout_below="@+id/gridLayout"/>

        <CheckBox
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/capture"
            android:id="@+id/captured"
            android:layout_marginTop="1dp"
            android:checked="false"
            android:layout_row="0"
            android:layout_column="1"/>
        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/calculate"
            android:id="@+id/button"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:layout_row="1"
            android:layout_column="0"/>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
            android:text="@string/totalscore"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:id="@+id/total"
            android:layout_row="1"
            android:layout_column="1"
            android:layout_gravity="right" />
    </GridLayout>

    <com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
        android:id="@+id/adView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"
        ads:adSize="BANNER"
        ads:adUnitId="ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/6300978111">
    </com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

It moves up and overlaps `EditText` because you set `alignParentBottom="true"`, thus when keyboard shows up, the layout parent bottom is the top of the `SoftKeyboard`.

You should probably get the solution by adding the all content `above` the `AdView` and by calling `adjustResize` on the `Activity` declaration in Manifest. On a side note, I'm not sure that calling `android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"` in `AdView` xml's widget is going to do something...

Therefore, to handle this behaviour, put the `AdView` at the top of layout's container and declare a sub-container for the rest of content:

```
<RelativeLayout ...>
    <AdView
        android:id="@+id/adView"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        ... />
    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_above="@id/adView"
        ...>
        <TextView ...>
        <GridLayout ...>
        <GridLayout ...>
    </RelativeLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Then, make the layout adjusting when keyboard shows up in Manifest.xml:

```
<activity
    android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"
    ... />
```

This should work as expected [on similar answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23153729/2668136). Also, there is another workaround: dynamically detect when the Keyboard is showing up and make the `AdView` invisible, and vice versa, but I think it does too much hard code than resolved into layout.

Answer (score 0):

Have you set `adjustResize` for `windowSoftInputMode` in your Manifest file? this will cause your UI layout to resize when the input method popup. if you don't want to resize, remove it.

```
    <activity
        android:name=".TestActivity"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize|stateAlwaysHidden"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
    </activity>
```

http://developer.android.com/training/keyboard-input/visibility.html#Respond